# PyMC3 autocorrplot() for any given array

Tags: python-2.7, statistics, pymc3

The `autocorrplot()` function gives the autocorrelation plot for the sampled data from the trace. 
If I already have a sample of data in the form of an array or list, can I use `autocorrplot()` to do the same? 
Is there any alternative to generate autocorrelation plots given a sequence of data?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`autocorrplot` is a wrapper around `matplotlib`'s `acorr`. To get a similar look to `pymc3`'s version, you can use something like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_array = np.random.normal(size=1000)

plt.acorr(my_array, detrend=plt.mlab.detrend_mean, maxlags=100)
plt.xlim(0, 100)
```

[image]

Note the call to `xlim` at the end, since by default `PyMC3` does not show negative correlations.